# Math mode in document title with R Markdown

Tags: math-mode, pandoc, markdown, rstudio

I was trying to put $\LaTeX$ in the document title but can't find a way to do so. I suppose that this is because I can't use latex packages with the document title. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here's what I have:

```
title: "Welcome to $\LaTeX$ Workshop"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  citation_package: natbib
  number_sections: yes
  link-citations: yes
bibliography: sample.bib
classoption: twocolumn
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lscape}
  - \usepackage[english]{babel}
  - \usepackage{multicol}
  - \setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
  - \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} # paragraph indentation
  - \setlength{\parskip}{8pt} # paragraph spacing
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \doublespacing
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char       (U+2028)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.96 \maketitle

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: U+2028 is unicode LINE SEPARATOR an unusual end-of-line marker, you shoudl probably delete the line and retype it making sure it just has a normal U+000A end of line marker.

Comment: `\LaTeX` isn't intended to be math mode so normally it would be `\LaTeX` not `$\LaTeX$` unless the `$` here are part of some non-tex markdown convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You need to escape the backslash using

```
title: "Welcome to \\LaTeX{} Workshop"
...
```

Or you can use a work-around:

```
---
title: "Welcome to LaTeX Workshop"
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \title{Welcome to \LaTeX{} Workshop}
...
---
```

The above approach removes all formatting from the title and resets it via the traditional way using `\title` *after* pandoc's `\title` insertion. This effectively overwrites it without the processing used by pandoc.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!